# Magento 'place order' redirects to shopping cart

Tags: magento

Every time I try to place an order rather than an order actually being placed I simply get redirected to the shopping cart.

Paypal express works fine however paypal standard payments gets the problem as above.

Lucas

Comment: Are there something in the logs?

Comment: any link or demo we can see your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to examine the ajax request. You can use Firefox with the "HTTPfox" extension to track the single requests. Just look for the step, where the redirect is executed - and start the http tracker. Then you see the response.

In the response you can see, what went wrong. I've got this error some weeks ago and it printed a full html page (with the report-number you can look up in the var/log/reports folder) or you can see a php error (maybe syntax error or bad sql query for example). If you get a blank page, you have to set the error_reporting to E_ALL.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thinkk that step is help.

- Log into Magento Admin
- Hover over "System" Click "Configuration"
- On the next page in the left menu under "Advanced"
- Under the check "Mage_Paypal" is Enable or Disable. if is Disable then Enable this options.

Then After the paypal is not redirect to paypal site. then please check your template code.

hope this will sure help you